# SQL append data based on multiple dates

Tags: sql

I have two tables; one contains encounter dates and the other order dates. They look like this:

```
id  enc_id enc_dt         
1   5      06/11/20       
1   6      07/21/21        
1   7      09/15/21        
2   2      04/21/20                  
2   5      05/05/20       

id  enc_id ord_dt         
1   1      03/7/20        
1   2      04/14/20       
1   3      05/15/20        
1   4      05/30/20                  
1   5      06/12/20
1   6      07/21/21
1   7      09/16/21
1   8      10/20/21
1   9      10/31/21                    
2   1      04/15/20        
2   2      04/21/20       
2   3      04/30/20
2   4      05/02/20
2   5      05/05/20
2   6      05/10/20
```

The order and encounter date can be the same, or differ slightly for the same encounter ID. I'm trying to get a table that contains all order dates before each encounter date. So the data would like this:

```
 id  enc_id    enc_dt    enc_key        
    1   1      03/7/20   5       
    1   2      04/14/20  5     
    1   3      05/15/20  5       
    1   4      05/30/20  5
    1   5      06/11/20  5
    1   1      03/7/20   6      
    1   2      04/14/20  6      
    1   3      05/15/20  6      
    1   4      05/30/20  6
    1   5      06/12/20  6
    1   6      07/21/21  6
    1   1      03/7/20   7    
    1   2      04/14/20  7    
    1   3      05/15/20  7       
    1   4      05/30/20  7
    1   5      06/12/20  7
    1   6      07/21/21  7
    1   7      09/15/21  7
    2   1      04/15/20  2
    2   2      04/21/20  2
    2   1      04/15/20  5     
    2   2      04/21/20  5     
    2   3      04/30/20  5
    2   4      05/02/20  5
    2   5      05/05/20  5
```

Is there a way to do this? I am having trouble figuring out how to append the orders and encounter table for each encounter based on orders that occur before a certain date.

Comment: Well, this is not really an SQL question, but one about practical relational database design. Besides, I can't really figure out how you define the id column: Is this an ID of the corresponding order?

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what you mean by corresponding order; it's an id variable for the same individual in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may join the two tables as the following:

```
SELECT O.id, O.enc_id, O.ord_dt, E.enc_id
FROM
order_tbl O 
JOIN encounter_tbl E
ON O.ord_dt <= E.enc_dt AND
   O.id = E.id
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMX6lHsV).

Comment: According to the expected output, it seems that there is a typo with the date value of (09/16/21) in the order table, it should be (09/15/21), and (06/11/20) in the encounter table should be (06/12/20).